# Need help on how to put the pet objects into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallPet
{
  private String name, ans;
  private int age; 
  private double weight;

  ArrayList<Pet>petList = new ArrayList<Pet>(1);
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  public void newPet()
  {
    do
    {

      System.out.println("Enter the Name of the Pet:");
      name = keyboard.nextLine();

      Boolean validAge=true;
      do
      {
        System.out.println("Enter the Age of the Pet:");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        if (age==(int)age)
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a correct age.");
          validAge = false;
        }
        else if (age<=0)
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a correct age.");
          validAge = false;
        }
      }while(!validAge);

      Boolean validWeight=true;
      do
      {
        System.out.println("Enter the Weight of the Pet:");
        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        if (weight==(int)weight)
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a correct weight.");
          validWeight = false;
        }
        else if (weight<=0)
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a correct weight.");
          validWeight = false;
        }
      }while(!validWeight);
      System.out.println("Again? Yes or No?");
      ans = keyboard.next();
    } while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));


    typeToArray()
    {
  }
}
```

I do not seem to get how to add these pet objects into an array and then sort them in order of weight lowest to biggest. here is the problem i am faced with.

Sort the Pet weight instead of by name. After displaying the sorted data on the screen, write the number and percentage of pets that are under 5 pounds, the number and percentage of pets that are 5 to 10 pounds, and the number and percentage of pets that are over 10 pounds.

Comment: I would want to know where is your class Pet maybe the problem is there.

Comment: of sorry its just a regular pet class. sorry its not here but i want to put the objects into an arraylist

Answer (score 2):

To add something to the `ArrayList`, use the `.add()` function.

To sort by weight, you need to override the default `compare()` function. Then, call `Collections.sort()` and put your `ArrayList` into the sort function as a parameter. Note that your `Pet` class should implement `Comparable`.